# Proof that the integral $ \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is zero

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f$ is differentiable in a region $U$, $f'$ is continuous in $U$ and $|f(x)-1|<1$ in $U$, proof that the integral $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ on any closed curve in $U$ is zero.

I know that if $f$ is differentiable then it is holomorphic. And if $F(z)=f'(z)$, $f$ holomorphic then the integral is zero. But I don't know how to use the hypothesis: $|f(x)-1|<1$

Comment: $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is the logarithmic derivative. What do you mean by integral?

Comment: Also what do you think of the case $|f(z)-1|\le 1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypothesis that $|f(x)-1|<1$ on $U$ implies that $f(U)$ is contained in the right half plane, where the principal branch of the logarithm is analytic with derivative $(\ln z)'=1/z$. By the chain rule, $(\ln f(z))'=f'(z)/f(z)$, so use $F(z)=\ln f(z)$ as in your question to get the result.

Comment: thanks again C: